# symbolic link in linux

Tags: ssh, rsync, symlink

I am copying code from a server using `rsync` over `ssh`:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress  root@ecash-staging:/to/path/file /path/
```

There is a symbolic link directory which cannot be copied, but I need the contents of the link target.

1) How can I copy that directory and then make a tar file and download or copy on local machine from server?

2) Or can we download that directory directly on to local machine? If yes, then how?

Comment: I removed your third question since we don't know why whoever set up your system chose to use symbolic links. Now, please [edit] your question and clarify why you need a `tar.gz` file. That doesn't seem related to your actual issue and questions here should only ask a single question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `man rsync`. The relevant section here is:

```
SYMBOLIC LINKS
       Three  basic  behaviors  are  possible when rsync encounters a symbolic
       link in the source directory.

       By default, symbolic links are  not  transferred  at  all.   A  message
       "skipping non-regular" file is emitted for any symlinks that exist.

       If --links is specified, then symlinks are recreated with the same tar‐
       get on the destination.  Note that --archive implies --links.

       If --copy-links is specified, then symlinks are "collapsed" by  copying
       their referent, rather than the symlink.
```

So, all you need is to add the `--copy-links` option:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress --copy-links root@ecash-staging:/to/path/file /path/
```

Comment: As a complement, I would like to add that many tools have options that determine how they act when encountering symbolic links (like `find` for example). Those are usually documented in their `man` page, so `man <tool>` is helpful most of the time for that matter.

Comment: @terdon thanks . --copy-links worked for me